# Swift Firebase removal of observers not removing

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, observers

I'm using Firebase listener to update state values for a remote camera. Once I have cycled through the camera lifecycle I want to remove the listeners so my camera does not start over and continue to take video.

Here is what I've done so far based on SO suggestions:

1) added FIRDatabaseHandle and called removeObserver(withHandle: handle) / no luck

2) simple called removeAllObservers() from the root reference to what you see below.

```
struct CameraActions {

let db = DataService.ds.db // this comes from a singleton used to for other Firebase calls
let uid = DataService.ds.curUser?.uid

var cameraRef:FIRDatabaseReference!

mutating func addCameraListener(cameraNum num:String, complete:@escaping(CameraStatus)->Void){
    cameraRef = db.child("camera").child(num).child("status")
    cameraRef.observe(.value, with: {
        snap in
        if let status = snap.value as? Int {

            switch status {
            case 0: complete(.ready)
            case 2: complete(.isRecording)
            case 4: complete(.hasStopped)
            case 5: complete(.problem)
            default:    print("App is waiting on camera")
            }
        }
    })
}

func cameraHasFinishedRecording(cameraNum num: String) {
    cameraRef.removeAllObservers() // latest attempt here
    db.child("camera").child(num).child("status").setValue(0) // this still triggers database call

}
```

Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Comment: Can you check how many times you call `addCameraListener` func

Comment: Do you want to check for all value changes in db **during** recording as well? Or just once when recording starts?

Comment: My VC calls the listener in ViewDidLoad (so called once to set).  An assortment of views are loaded based on the state of the returned values from the listener. Yes, I do check for value changes during recording which, are in funcs not listed above in order to condense.

Answer (score 0):

Firebase works exactly as advertised. The removal of the observer was working but, another observer that should've been a single observer was firing. Thanks for the input and sorry for wasting your time.

Cheers!